Get local files in blazor + monogame(kniEngine)
I have a folder with .json files and by default im getting them with
Directory.GetFiles("Content/animations");

and then read them. But in blazor platform i have no access to this folder anymore.
Is there any way to read theese files?

manifest but is seems like it can only be accessible from .razor files.
Http.GetStringAsync, but there is no Http using
Just reading 'Content/animations', 'wwwroot/Content/animations' but not found


You didn't say whether you are using Blazor Server or Blazor WebAssembly. System.IO.File and System.IO.Directory do not work in Blazor WebAssembly as you might expect. See my answer here. You will likely need to use HttpClient. Your question needs more information to be answerable. How do I ask a good question?
